# Possible to get attribute of method in a second method call

Tags: c#, attributes

```
[TestAttribute(Name = "Test")]
public void Test()
{
    Test2();
}

public viod Test2()
{
    Console.Write(TestAttribute.Name);
}
```

As shown above, is it possible to get the information of the attribute of Test when called in Test2?

Preferable without stacktrace.

Comment: When you say "Preferable without stacktrace," what do you mean?  You will almost certainly need to use `StackTrace` to find out what the calling method is, so why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: why not mark the second method with the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using stacktrace you could use `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` and pass it to your secondary method.

```
[TestAttribute(Name = "Test")]
public void Test()
{
    Test2(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
}

public viod Test2(MethodBase sender)
{
    var attr = sender.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
    if(attr != null)
    {
       TestAttribute ta = attr as TestAttribute;
       Console.WriteLine(ta.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this method, but I think all in all it would be better to just pass the attribute with the method?

Comment: @TheunArbeider That is all well and good, but what if you change the attribute on your method? Your code has to change. I would personally keep the above code, it allows for change.

Comment: I didn't know about MethodBase, +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know how to get to the caller without stacktrace in your case:

```
[TestAttribute(Name = "Test")]
static void Test() {
    Test2();
}

static void Test2() {
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(1);
    var attributes = st.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false);
    TestAttribute testAttribute = attributes[0] as TestAttribute;
    if (testAttribute != null) {
        Console.Write(testAttribute.Name);
    }
}
```

An alternative is to explicitly pass the method information to the function:

```
[TestAttribute(Name = "Test")]
void TestMethod() {
    MethodInfo thisMethod = GetType().GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    Test3(thisMethod);
}

static void Test3(MethodInfo caller) {
    var attributes = caller.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false);
    TestAttribute testAttribute = attributes[0] as TestAttribute;
    if (testAttribute != null) {
        Console.Write(testAttribute.Name);
    }
}
```

By the way, this does not really look like something you want to do with reflection; I think that in this case the way to go is just this :)

```
void Test() {
    Test2(name);
}

void Test2(string name) {
    Console.Write(name);
}
```

Comment: OP said preferably without stack trace?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Preferably means it's not a strict requirement, right?

Comment: Your correct and I agree, but would probably be useful to explain why it's not possible :)

Comment: @LukeHennerley: well, I was not completely sure there's not an other way to get to the caller of a function (altough if such method existed I would strongly suspect it's using the stack trace under the hood) :)